# Return reference from binary search tree C++

Tags: c++, search, recursion, binary-search-tree

Consider the following search function in my binary search tree.

```
template <class elemType>
elemType& BSTree<elemType>::search(const elemType & searchItem) const
{
    std::cout << "in 1st teir search" << std::endl;
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Tree is empty, and there for no data will be in this tree." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Entering 2nd teir search" << std::endl;
        return search(root, searchItem);
    } //End else
} //End search(1param)

template <class elemType>
elemType& BSTree<elemType>::search(nodeType<elemType>* node, const elemType& dataToFind) const
{
    elemType found;

    if (node == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Not found. Node is null." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (node->data == dataToFind)
        {
            std::cout << "Data found" << std::endl;
            found = node->data;
        }
        else if (node->data < dataToFind)
        {
            std::cout << "Data not found, searching to the RIGHT" << std::endl;
            found = search(node->rLink, dataToFind);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Data not found, searching to the LEFT" << std::endl;
            found = search(node->lLink, dataToFind);
        }
    } //End else
    return found;
} //End search(2param)
```

Whenever I access/ search for a data that isn't root my program crashes when I go to assign that data.

What am I missing?

Note:Understand that perhaps I could just use a function pointer in my traversal to do return values but for the purpose I'm using my tree for search will return a reference to the object.

Comment: Off-topic: In first version of `search`, your `if` path doesn't return anything or throw. Initializing `elemType found;` with a `nullptr` is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't returning a reference to the node you are looking for, you are returning a reference to `found`, which has automatic storage and will be destroyed when the function exits.

To fix this, you could make `found` a pointer, store the address of the node in it, then `return *found;` at the end of the function.

Comment: So both functions will return a pointer or just the 2nd tier one?
I believe I tried that earlier and got a "invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Type&' from an rvalue of 'Type'

Comment: You can keep them both returning references, just use a pointer internally so you can update it.

Comment: In fact, you might be better off returning a pointer so you can represent the case where you can't find the node.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the help. Secondly, sorry I'm such a noob.

So all i have changed is found is now a pointer and I return a pointer from my tier2 function but when i get to any line that assigns found ie

found = node->data;
found = search(node->rLink, dataToFind);
found = search(node->lLink, dataToFind);

I get this error:
error: cannot convert 'Unit' to 'Unit*' in assignment|

(note unit is user defined data type)

Comment: That's not how you use pointers. You need to assign the address of the object you want to point to, like `found = &node->data;`.

Comment: oh dont worry. Forgot to use reference operator on those lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79931/discussion-between-master-sketchiggle-and-tartanllama).

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to use references, you can define a static instance of a `Node` that represents "empty".  e.g. `BSTree<T>::None`.  Then return a reference to that when nothing is found.